# Submanifold realization of differential forms - finding a submanifold which nontrivially intersect another submanifold

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, differential-topology, homology-cohomology, smooth-manifolds

While trying to prove de Rham's theorem on my own, I came up with the following question:

> If $M$ is a closed orientable $n-$manifold and $X$ is a closed
>   orientable $p$-submanifold of $M$ which represents a nontrivial
>   element of the $p$-th homology group of $M$, then is there a closed
>   orientable $(n-p)$-submanifold $Y$ of $M$ whose oriented
>   intersection number with $X$ is nonzero?

I wish to know whether the above statement is true, and if it is false, then what some simple counterexamples are.

Thank you in advance!

---

Well, let me add a few words on how I came up with the question. I was trying to prove de Rham's theorem, which says that the natural map $i:H_{dR}^p(M;\mathbb{R})\rightarrow H_p(M;\mathbb{R})^*\simeq H^p(M;\mathbb{R})$ is an isomorphism. In order to prove surjectivity, I first wanted to show that if $[X]\in H_p(M;\mathbb{R})$ is a nontrivial element of the homology, then there is an element $[\omega]\in H_{dR}^p(M;\mathbb{R})$ that "detects" such nontrivial homology. In attempting to prove the last statement, I divided the statement into two parts:

1. Find an element $Y\in H_{n-p}(M;\mathbb{R})$ such that $I(X, Y) \neq 0$ where $I(X,Y)$ is the oriented intersection number beween $X$ and $Y$. (Then $I(-,Y)$ is a linear functional on $H_p(M;\mathbb{R})$ under which the image of $X$ is nonzero.)
2. Find an element $[\omega]\in H_{dR}^p(M;\mathbb{R})$ such that $\omega(X)=I(X,Y)$.

At this moment, I am not even sure if either of the above two statement (finding $Y$ and finding $[\omega]$) is valid or not. But anyway I found this quite interesting, and from this I hope to understand better about the interaction between the oriented intersection number (defined differential topologically) and the de Rham cohomology.

Comment: Note that not all homology classes are represented by submanifolds.